# What's the order?

Tags: pattern, sequence

Below are five sequences of the digits 0-9 but each have been sorted based on a single criterion.

1) $1260459378$

2) $1742350698$

3) $0152469378$

4) $5463728190$

5) $1235904687$

Name the criteria used to sort each sequence.

Comment: Are you saying that you have individual digits (One time each of 0, 1, 2,...) and then sorted them by a single criterium to get the sequence in 1)? And then applied the same criterion to a new set of 10 digits and got the sequence in 2)? etc. ?  Or is the criterium different for each of the five?

Comment: @BmyGuest A different criterion was used for sorting each of the five. They each started out as `0123456789` before being sorted.

Comment: For 3) Prob wrong but, is it perhaps 01425... instead of 01524... ?

Comment: @Prim3numbah It is correct as is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note 1:** Number 3 was solved by hagfy in the comments.

**Note 2:** Where two or more digits are equal in any ordering below, the digits are sorted numerically.

1.

> Sort the digits by number of letters in the spelling.

2.

> Sort the digits by number of segments used in 7-segment display.

3.

> Sort by number of letters in the Roman numeral representation of the digit.

4.

> Sort by absolute distance from 5.
>  Alternatively, sort digits by number of dashes in Morse Code representation.

5.

> Sort by number of dots in braille representation of the digit.

Comment: I think 3 could be rot13(gur ahzore bs punenpgref va ebzna ahzrenyf)

Comment: @hagfy Brilliant, that must be it!

Comment: All of those are correct!